# DB Transaction not rolling back [Laravel 7.3]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm running Laravel 7.3 on an app, and I feel like this is potentially a Laravel framework bug because I'm racking my brain on this...

I've got a DB Transaction with model saves within it, all within a try/catch but it's still saving the model updates, and I just can't see why because it hits the `catch()` and the response json hits, so I assume the rollback is running, yet the database is still updating.

```
try {
    DB::beginTransaction();

    foreach ($models as $model) {
        $model->rungroup_id = $rungroup->id;
        $model->zone_id = $rungroup->getFirstZoneID();
        $model->delivery_status = 'next';
        $model->save();
    }

    DB::commit();

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
} catch (Throwable | Exception $e) {
    DB::rollBack();

    Log::error($e);

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
    ], 500);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

After updating Laravel and many other attempts at rewriting the code to see if I made a silly mistake, I ended up finding that the person who created the database tables set the Table engine to `MyISAM` rather than `InnoDB` which is required for the DB transactions... I wish Laravel threw an error so I would've known, but this has definitely saved my sanity, and hope it helps others.

Comment: After pulling and scratching my head for several hours, you finally saved my day. Thank you.